# How can I track / analyze Meteor DDP calls

Tags: meteor, analyzer, sniffer, tracker, ddp

While programming a Meteor complex application it would be useful to track / analyze / sniff the DDP traffic in order optimize it and make the app fast and efficient. For example it would be very interesting to see the publications and methods calls flow.

In this situation what tools could be used?

Answer (score 3):

There's also a Chrome Devtools extension for monitoring DDP traffic - https://github.com/thebakeryio/meteor-ddp-monitor

Comment: Recommendation requests for off-site resources or tools are off-topic on Stack Overflow. If you answer them, you specifically reinforce the belief that Stack Overflow is a good place to answer those questions. It is not. Please don't answer these questions even if you know a good answer as most answers will be highly opinionated ("I personally like..."). You can open the flag dialogue on the question and see the close reason in full under the **off-topic** category, or in the [help/on-topic]. You should also not even answer in a comment, as the effect is similar to an actual answer.

Answer (score 2):

Adding [kadira](https://github.com/meteorhacks/kadira) would be the best solution to monitor and optimize publish/subscribe, method call and ddp in Meteor apps.

**Installation**

`meteor add meteorhacks:kadira`

Read the [Getting started guide](https://kadira.io/academy/getting-started-with-kadira/) to learn more about kadira.

If you want to analyze only the ddp  you can use [ddp-analyzer](https://github.com/arunoda/meteor-ddp-analyzer).

`npm install -g ddp-analyzer`

Answer (score 2):

DDP is just JSON over WebSockets (or an emulation of it). You can simply use Dev Tools network tab to sniff out the messages.